# Approaching for drawing a diagram using HTML and CSS inside my asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I want to draw a diagram similar to the following

[image]

inside my asp.net web application.. now i do not want to show the image as is, since i will be adding hyperlinks for the actual text. so for example when users click on "Management System" they will be redirected to a documentations site about it.. so can anyone adivce how i can draw this using HTML and css ??

Comment: You write code to do it. Just like everything else on Stack Overflow, make an attempt. If you get stuck at a specific part, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you're only after the links and the content itself isn't going to be dynamic, I would suggest using an image with [map tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp). It's the fastest and easiest way. Otherwise, as suggested, write the code to do it in ASP and style it with CSS, that's how things are done.